# Issue with CallbackQuery in Telegram bot

Tags: java, callback, telegram-bot

I'm trying to create an Inline Keyboard Markup in my telegram bot using java (Maven project using TelegramBotsApi v 6.7.0). This includes handling call back queries from user to take some decision later.

The Inline keyboard code is

```
 private InlineKeyboardMarkup createMenuMarkup() {


        List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> inlineButtons = new ArrayList<>();
        List<InlineKeyboardButton> inlineKeyboardButtonList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<InlineKeyboardButton> inlineKeyboardButtonList2 = new ArrayList<>();

        InlineKeyboardButton inlineKeyboardButton1 = InlineKeyboardButton.builder()
                .text("Choice 1")
                .callbackData("1")
                .url("https://www.google.com")
                .build();

        InlineKeyboardButton inlineKeyboardButton2 = InlineKeyboardButton.builder()
                .text("Choice 2")
                .callbackData("2")
                .build();

        InlineKeyboardButton inlineKeyboardButton3 = InlineKeyboardButton.builder()
                .text("Choice 3")
                .callbackData("3")
                .build();
        InlineKeyboardButton inlineKeyboardButton4 = InlineKeyboardButton.builder()
                .text("Choice 4")
                .callbackData("4")
                .build();


        inlineKeyboardButtonList1.add(inlineKeyboardButton1);
        inlineKeyboardButtonList1.add(inlineKeyboardButton2);
        inlineKeyboardButtonList2.add(inlineKeyboardButton3);
        inlineKeyboardButtonList2.add(inlineKeyboardButton4);
        inlineButtons.add(inlineKeyboardButtonList1);
        inlineButtons.add(inlineKeyboardButtonList2);

        return InlineKeyboardMarkup
                .builder()
                .keyboard(inlineButtons)
                .build();
    }
```

and to handle the call back I used if statement with a handling function

```
else if(update.getMessage().getText().equals("/menu"))
        {
            sendMarkup(createMenuMarkup());
        }
        else if(update.hasCallbackQuery())
        {
            **System.out.println("Callback Received");
            handleCallback(update);**
        }
```

```
    private void handleCallback(Update update)
    {
        String callData = update.getCallbackQuery().getData();
        System.out.println(callData);
        switch (callData)
        {
            case "1":
                sendMessage("You chose 1");
                break;
            case "2":
                sendMessage("You chose 2");
                break;
            case "3":
                sendMessage("You chose 3");
                break;
            case "4":
                sendMessage("You chose 4");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the call back query isn't recognized as and update in `onUpdateReceived`
so it doesn't go in `onUpdateReceived` function at all as if the button in the menu was never clicked.

What should I do?

I tried to change the version I'm using to 5.4.0 and I still have the same issue.

I also tried to use buttons functionality with `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` and it worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

Please use TelegramApiv 6.7.0, it supports new features of telegram API.
After reading your code, there are some point was missing in `if(update.getMessage()...)` this will error. we should check `update.hasMessage()` first to prevent exception.

---

Any ways, you can review my code, I wrote follow your structures.

```java
public class InlineBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        if(update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().getText().equals("/menu")){ // check hasMessage first! if not check hasMessage(), it call getMessage(), it breaks into runtimeException
            String chatId = String.valueOf(update.getMessage().getChatId());
            sendMarkup(createMenuMarkup(), chatId);
        } else if(update.hasCallbackQuery()){
            System.out.println("Callback Received");
            handleCallback(update);
        }
    }

    private void sendMarkup(InlineKeyboardMarkup menuMarkup, String chatId) {
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
        sendMessage.setChatId(chatId);
        sendMessage.setText("Please choose button below:"); // if not set Text message, it won't send
        sendMessage.setReplyMarkup(menuMarkup);
        try {
            execute(sendMessage);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return "...";
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return "...";
    }

    private InlineKeyboardMarkup createMenuMarkup() {
        List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> inlineButtons = new ArrayList<>();
        List<InlineKeyboardButton> inlineKeyboardButtonList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<InlineKeyboardButton> inlineKeyboardButtonList2 = new ArrayList<>();

        InlineKeyboardButton inlineKeyboardButton1 = InlineKeyboardButton.builder()
                .text("Choice 1")
                .callbackData("1")
                .url("https://www.google.com")
                .build();

        InlineKeyboardButton inlineKeyboardButton2 = InlineKeyboardButton.builder()
                .text("Choice 2")
                .callbackData("2")
                .build();

        InlineKeyboardButton inlineKeyboardButton3 = InlineKeyboardButton.builder()
                .text("Choice 3")
                .callbackData("3")
                .build();
        InlineKeyboardButton inlineKeyboardButton4 = InlineKeyboardButton.builder()
                .text("Choice 4")
                .callbackData("4")
                .build();


        inlineKeyboardButtonList1.add(inlineKeyboardButton1);
        inlineKeyboardButtonList1.add(inlineKeyboardButton2);
        inlineKeyboardButtonList2.add(inlineKeyboardButton3);
        inlineKeyboardButtonList2.add(inlineKeyboardButton4);
        inlineButtons.add(inlineKeyboardButtonList1);
        inlineButtons.add(inlineKeyboardButtonList2);

        return InlineKeyboardMarkup
                .builder()
                .keyboard(inlineButtons)
                .build();
    }

    private void handleCallback(Update update) {
        String callData = update.getCallbackQuery().getData();
        String chatId = String.valueOf(update.getCallbackQuery().getMessage().getChatId());
        System.out.println(callData);
        switch (callData) {
            case "1":
                sendMessage("You chose 1", chatId);
                break;
            case "2":
                sendMessage("You chose 2", chatId);
                break;
            case "3":
                sendMessage("You chose 3", chatId);
                break;
            case "4":
                sendMessage("You chose 4", chatId);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void sendMessage(String msg, String chatId) {
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage(chatId, msg);
        try {
            execute(sendMessage);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope my code, it helps you to improve your code and handle error. Please read this [short blog](https://monsterdeveloper.gitbook.io/java-telegram-bot-tutorial/) tutorial and try, you will get to know more about the framework.

Comment: thank's .I already use v6.7.0. I think the additional check on `update.hasMessage()` will solve my problem as after some trials before your reply I found that placing the `handleCallback(update)`  call as the first line of `onUpdateReceived(Update update)` function worked fine and I didn't know why then. I think now I know why. Again thank you for your consideration.